# How do I achieve that the animation (making one pic big and the others gone) for 3 pictures that each take up 33% is correct for the middle one too

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website where I currently have three pictures which each take up 33% of the site. These are 1920x1080 pictures and put in as background. I now wanted an animation which made the middle one slide extend to both sides and the other two gone.

I first tried this

```
html
<body>
    <div class="imagesplits">
        <div class="imagesplit"></div>
        <div class="imagesplit"></div>
        <div class="imagesplit"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
css
html,
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

.imagesplits {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
}

.imagesplit {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}

.imagesplit:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url("bild1TEST.jpg");
    animation: widthsmaller 2s;
}

.imagesplit:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: url("bild2TEST.png");
    animation: widthbigger 2s;
    width: 100%;
}

.imagesplit:nth-child(3) {
    background-image: url("bild3TEST.jpg");
    animation: widthsmaller 2s;
}


@keyframes widthbigger {
    from {
        width: 33.33333%
    }

    to {
        width: 100%
    }
}

@keyframes widthsmaller {
    from {
        width: 33.33333%
    }

    to {
        width: 0%
    }
}
```

The first problem I encountered was that the picture did not extend but rather just slid to the left while extending the right, because the split made it so that each picture was the 33% left side of the full 1920x1080 picture. I then tried to fix that by adjusting the background positions.

```
css
.imagesplit:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url("bild1TEST.jpg");
    animation: widthsmaller 2s;
}

.imagesplit:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: url("bild2TEST.png");
    animation: widthbigger 2s;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: calc(100% + 640px) 0;
}

.imagesplit:nth-child(3) {
    background-image: url("bild3TEST.jpg");
    animation: widthsmaller 2s;
    background-position: calc(100% - 1920px) 0;
}
```

The problem now is that when the animation is finished the picture looks cursed, as there is a bit (I'm guessing 640px) is missing on the right and added on the left. Also the animation was better, but not good. So how do I achieve that the middle picture doesn't slide from right to left anymore but simply extends both left and right?

Thank you.